# Best practices for customizing themes

Tags: windows-phone-7, themes

What are the best practices for customizing themes for a WP7 application (font family, colours, etc)? Should I be sticking to the [standard names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and replacing them or creating new resource names and using those?

ie. "PhoneFontFamilyNormal" or "MyAppFontFamilyNormal"? "PhoneTextNormalStyle" or "MyAppTextNormalStyle"?

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769554%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) on the subject seems to focus soley on playing the straight and norrow, even though custom themes are supported (if disueded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally create my own resources with unique names and use those. This avoids any confusion relating to precedence (I can't recall right now the resource look-up mechanism in Silverlight, I know that it is a simplification of the WPF one - which is a little complex!).

One important consideration is whether you will support dark / light themes. The standard theme resources like `PhoneBackgroundBrush` will honour the users theme. Therefore, if you wish to support Dark / Light I would recommend deriving your own theme from the standard one, for example, you might derive your background brush from `PhoneBackgroundColor`.

Comment: That's the direction I've started down as it makes the most sense (for the reasons you mentioned. dark/light theme support is indeed another issue, but I have some ideas about how I may tackle that.

Comment: In addition, I ended up coming up with a practical solution to managing custom, theme-sensitive, resources which I [wrote up on my blog](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/). I've also previous included the code on [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131982/how-to-setup-button-background-image-either-theme-is-dark-or-white) just in case.