# How to avoid theme (lite&dark) efects on windows phone applications?

Tags: windows-phone-7, themes

I developed one Windows Phone 7 application.
After installed the app to my mobile device (in emulator too) I'm experiencing the theme problem.

Means there are two themes in windows phone, LITE and DARK.

When I set my theme to dark and execute my app , it looks OK,
 but if I change the theme to LITE everything is reverted.

It means white lables become black, and black background become white.

So I need a solution to my app, so that the user can set any theme, but it doesn't effect the appearrence of application.

Comment: i think you are using the default resource dictionaries of colors for controls' background. Instead, you must specify your own colors/brushes where ever possible. This way, you can get rid of themeing effect. you can see example of Microsoft Office Mobile where the background is set as white, which remains white irrespective of theme applied.

Comment: however, avoid over-themefication of your app, as it may look absurd on device. For fonts, you must use inbuild resource dictionaries for setting font details like name, size, bold etc...

Comment: can u have any themes?and microsoft urls too

Comment: you cannot have themes other than system defined themes, but you can create a resource dictionary where you can specify x:Key to resources you want to define and use these resources as StaticResource in controls.

Comment: and also, you cannot add/install themes into your device. These themes are installed as default and cannot be changed except for the accent colors

Comment: no man, you must create it yourself as it depends on your app idea

Comment: ofcourse but i dont know which color in resource occupies the colors of menu bar, fonts like...

Comment: see, it depends on your application. what styling would you like to give... its all ur creativity

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't hardcode colours, brushes, etc, but instead use `{StaticResource ResourceName}` and use resources from [Theme Resources for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)
2. Make sure that *every* `TextBlock` and `TextBox` has a `Style` associated with it (available values from the same link)
3. If you have have custom resources (colours, images, etc) that you wish to be theme-aware you are free to use the `ThemeResourceDictionary` I [posted on my blog](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2011/06/11/practical-support-for-light-dark-themes-on-windows-phone-7/) (and also [for this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131982/how-to-setup-button-background-image-either-theme-is-dark-or-white)). I promise to commit the code to [GitHub](https://github.com/richardszalay/wp-themeresourcedictionary) one of these days and also create a NuGet package.

Comment: can you define "sample theme"?

Comment: i want a theme just like dark theme in windows phone

Comment: You can change your theme to dark in systen settings. If you are asking if you can make just _your_ application dark even if the user's theme is white, the answer is: not without defining your own set of theme resources.